# Retrieving all the column names with a specific value

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write query which should return the column names which has specific value

for example

```
column_1 column_2    Column_3   Column_4  Column_5  Column_6
good     good        good       very good Very good bad
```

I've to get the column names whose values are good and very good

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, Column_3, Column_4, Column_5, Column_6
FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE column_1 IN ('good', 'very good')
OR    column_2 IN ('good', 'very good')
OR    column_3 IN ('good', 'very good')
OR    column_4 IN ('good', 'very good')
OR    column_5 IN ('good', 'very good')
OR    column_6 IN ('good', 'very good')
```

( as an aside, *your* column names are all bad and meaningless )

Comment: thank you. It's working fine. column names i've mentioned here are not the one am using. is there anyway i could get all the column names without checking out each and every columns.

Comment: @rohin: no, but  it's often a flaw in your design if you have two many similar columns. That could mean that you should normalize your table. Create a new table that links to this table via foreign-key. Then all of these columns are rows in that table. That will increase readability, maintainability and performance.